# C3.js stacked bar chart with overlap per category

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I want to get the second data group (data3, data4) overlapping the first data group (data1, data2) in order to see both in one stacked bar chart.
That brings me to following requirements for data group (data3, data4):

- must be on y2 axis based on data group value and not on single data 3 or 4
- must be overlapped with data group (data1, data2) and formatted    thinner
- data 3 must be formatted transparrent

(see Excel-screenshot below)

[Example of two stacked bar charts, overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbm6x.png)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
columns: [
    ['data1', 30],
    ['data2', 130],
    ['data3', 50],
    ['data4', 100]
    ],
type: 'bar',
groups: [
    ['data1', 'data2'], ['data3', 'data4']
    ]
  },
});
```

- C3 version: 0.5.4
- D3 version: d3.v5.min.js
- Browser: Version 66.0.3359.139 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)
- OS: Windows 10

thanks for all supports
Michael

Comment: Can you share a working jsfiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: Hi, pls find the fiddle. my target would be to have the green bar (Correction)  inside the blue bar (Total).
https://jsfiddle.net/el_gaucho/kxurrLj6/2/